# class_weight argument in Keras model.fit() method returns InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

[Google Colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1GdPchAQiB9S5qUQ5L-a3u1ivEq2OQryc?usp=sharing) with the issue replicated. Please unfold if any cell is hidden.

I have the following Keras model:

Yesterday I moved to TensorFlow 2.2.0 from 2.1.0

```py
from collections import Counter

def get_class_weights(y):
    counter = Counter(y)
    majority = max(counter.values())
    return  {cls: float(majority/count) for cls, count in counter.items()}

dict_test=get_class_weights(np.ravel(y_train, order='C'))
dict_test

"{0: 1.0, 1: 8.299129075480126}"
```

```py
def create_fit_keras_model(hparams,
                           version_data_control,
                           optimizer_name,
                           validation_method,
                           callbacks,
                           optimizer_version = None):

    sentenceLength_actors = X_train_seq_actors.shape[1] #17
    vocab_size_frequent_words_actors = len(actors_tokenizer.word_index) #20000

    sentenceLength_plot = X_train_seq_plot.shape[1] #20
    vocab_size_frequent_words_plot = len(plot_tokenizer.word_index) #20000

    sentenceLength_features = X_train_seq_features.shape[1] #43
    vocab_size_frequent_words_features = len(features_tokenizer.word_index) #20000

    sentenceLength_reviews = X_train_seq_reviews.shape[1] #257
    vocab_size_frequent_words_reviews = len(reviews_tokenizer.word_index) #20000

    model = keras.Sequential(name='{0}_{1}dim_{2}batchsize_{3}lr_{4}decaymultiplier_{5}'.format(sequential_model_name, 
                                                                                                str(hparams[HP_EMBEDDING_DIM]), 
                                                                                                str(hparams[HP_HIDDEN_UNITS]),
                                                                                                str(hparams[HP_LEARNING_RATE]), 
                                                                                                str(hparams[HP_DECAY_STEPS_MULTIPLIER]),
                                                                                                version_data_control))
    actors = keras.Input(shape=(sentenceLength_actors,), name='actors_input')
    plot = keras.Input(shape=(sentenceLength_plot,), name='plot_input')
    features = keras.Input(shape=(sentenceLength_features,), name='features_input')
    reviews = keras.Input(shape=(sentenceLength_reviews,), name='reviews_input')

    emb1 = layers.Embedding(input_dim = vocab_size_frequent_words_actors + 2,
                            output_dim = hparams[HP_EMBEDDING_DIM],
                            embeddings_initializer = 'uniform',
                            mask_zero = True,
                            input_length = sentenceLength_actors,
                            name="actors_embedding_layer")(actors)
    
    encoded_layer1 = layers.GlobalMaxPooling1D(name="globalmaxpooling_actors_layer")(emb1)
    
    emb2 = layers.Embedding(input_dim = vocab_size_frequent_words_plot + 2,
                            output_dim = hparams[HP_EMBEDDING_DIM],
                            embeddings_initializer = 'uniform',
                            mask_zero = True,
                            input_length = sentenceLength_plot,
                            name="plot_embedding_layer")(plot)
    
    encoded_layer2 = layers.GlobalMaxPooling1D(name="globalmaxpooling_plot_summary_Layer")(emb2)

    emb3 = layers.Embedding(input_dim = vocab_size_frequent_words_features + 2,
                            output_dim = hparams[HP_EMBEDDING_DIM],
                            embeddings_initializer = 'uniform',
                            mask_zero = True,
                            input_length = sentenceLength_features,
                            name="features_embedding_layer")(features)
    
    encoded_layer3 = layers.GlobalMaxPooling1D(name="globalmaxpooling_movie_features_layer")(emb3)
    
    emb4 = layers.Embedding(input_dim = vocab_size_frequent_words_reviews + 2,
                            output_dim = hparams[HP_EMBEDDING_DIM],
                            embeddings_initializer = 'uniform',
                            mask_zero = True,
                            input_length = sentenceLength_reviews,
                            name="reviews_embedding_layer")(reviews)
    
    encoded_layer4 = layers.GlobalMaxPooling1D(name="globalmaxpooling_user_reviews_layer")(emb4)
    
    merged = layers.concatenate([encoded_layer1, encoded_layer2, encoded_layer3, encoded_layer4], axis=-1)

    dense_layer_1 = layers.Dense(hparams[HP_HIDDEN_UNITS],
                                 kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(neural_network_parameters['l2_regularization']),
                                   activation='relu',
                                   name="1st_dense_hidden_layer_concatenated_inputs")(merged)
    
    layers.Dropout(0.0)(dense_layer_1)
    
    output_layer = layers.Dense(y_train.shape[1], 
                                activation='sigmoid',
                                name='output_layer')(dense_layer_1)

    model = keras.Model(inputs=[actors, plot, features, reviews], outputs=output_layer, name='{0}_{1}dim_{2}batchsize_{3}lr_{4}decaymultiplier_{5}'.format(sequential_model_name, 
                                                                                                                                                           str(hparams[HP_EMBEDDING_DIM]), 
                                                                                                                                                           str(hparams[HP_HIDDEN_UNITS]),
                                                                                                                                                           str(hparams[HP_LEARNING_RATE]), 
                                                                                                                                                           str(hparams[HP_DECAY_STEPS_MULTIPLIER]),
                                                                                                                                                           version_data_control))
    print(model.summary())
    
    pruning_schedule = tfmot.sparsity.keras.PolynomialDecay(initial_sparsity=0.0, 
                                                            final_sparsity=0.4, 
                                                            begin_step=600, 
                                                            end_step=1000)
    
    model_for_pruning = tfmot.sparsity.keras.prune_low_magnitude(model, pruning_schedule=pruning_schedule)
    
    if optimizer_name=="adam" and optimizer_version is None:
        
        optimizer = optimizer_adam_v2(hparams[HP_LEARNING_RATE], hparams[HP_DECAY_STEPS_MULTIPLIER], X_train_seq_actors.shape[0], optimizer_parameters['validation_split_ratio'], hparams[HP_HIDDEN_UNITS])
        
    elif optimizer_name=="sgd" and optimizer_version is None:
        
        optimizer = optimizer_sgd_v1(hparams[HP_LEARNING_RATE])
        
    elif optimizer_name=="rmsprop" and optimizer_version is None:
        
        optimizer = optimizer_rmsprop_v1(hparams[HP_LEARNING_RATE])

    model_for_pruning.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
                              loss=tfa.losses.sigmoid_focal_crossentropy,
                              metrics=[tfa.metrics.F1Score(len(y_train[0].tolist()), average="micro")]
    
    #plot model's structure
    plot_model(model, to_file=os.path.join(os.getcwd(), '{0}\\{1}_{2}batchsize_{3}lr_{4}decaymultiplier_{5}.png'.format(folder_path_model_saved, 
                                                                                                                        network_structure_file_name,
                                                                                                                        str(hparams[HP_EMBEDDING_DIM]), 
                                                                                                                        str(hparams[HP_HIDDEN_UNITS]),
                                                                                                                        str(hparams[HP_LEARNING_RATE]), 
                                                                                                                        str(hparams[HP_DECAY_STEPS_MULTIPLIER]),
                                                                                                                        version_data_control)))
    start_time = time.time()
    
    steps_per_epoch=int(np.ceil((X_train_seq_actors.shape[0]*optimizer_parameters['validation_split_ratio'])//hparams[HP_HIDDEN_UNITS]))
    
    print("\nSteps per epoch on current run: {0}".format(steps_per_epoch))
    
    if validation_method=="validation_split":

        fitted_model=model_for_pruning.fit([X_train_seq_actors, X_train_seq_plot, X_train_seq_features, X_train_seq_reviews],
                                           y_train, 
                                           steps_per_epoch=int(np.ceil((X_train_seq_actors.shape[0]*optimizer_parameters['validation_split_ratio'])//hparams[HP_HIDDEN_UNITS])),
                                           epochs=fit_parameters["epoch"],
                                           batch_size=hparams[HP_HIDDEN_UNITS],
                                           validation_split=fit_parameters['validation_data_ratio'],
                                           callbacks=callbacks,
                                           use_multiprocessing=True,
                                           class_weight=dict_test
                                           )

    elif validation_method=="validation_data":
        
        fitted_model=model_for_pruning.fit([X_train_seq_actors, X_train_seq_plot, X_train_seq_features, X_train_seq_reviews], 
                                           y_train,
#                                            class_weight=class_weight_dict,
                                           steps_per_epoch=int(np.ceil((X_train_seq_actors.shape[0]*optimizer_parameters['validation_split_ratio'])//hparams[HP_HIDDEN_UNITS])),
                                           epochs=fit_parameters["epoch"],
                                           verbose=fit_parameters["verbose_fit"],
                                           batch_size=hparams[HP_HIDDEN_UNITS],
                                           validation_data=([X_test_seq_actors, X_test_seq_plot, X_test_seq_features, X_test_seq_reviews],
                                                            y_test),
                                           callbacks=callbacks
                                           )
    #save the model
    save_model(model,
               folder_path_model_saved,
               "{0}_{1}dim_{2}batchsize_{3}lr_{4}decaymultiplier_{5}".format(saved_model_name,
                                                                             str(hparams[HP_EMBEDDING_DIM]), 
                                                                             str(hparams[HP_HIDDEN_UNITS]), 
                                                                             str(hparams[HP_LEARNING_RATE]), 
                                                                             str(hparams[HP_DECAY_STEPS_MULTIPLIER]), 
                                                                             version_data_control))

    elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
    
    print("\nTraining time of the multi-input keras model has finished. Duration {} secs".format(format_timespan(elapsed_time)))
    
    _, accuracy = model_for_pruning.evaluate([X_test_seq_actors, X_test_seq_plot, X_test_seq_features, X_test_seq_reviews], y_test, batch_size=hparams[HP_HIDDEN_UNITS], verbose=2)

    return accuracy, model_for_pruning, fitted_model
```

```py
def run(run_dir, hparams, version_data_control, optimizer_name, validation_method, callbacks):
    with tf.summary.create_file_writer(run_dir).as_default():
        hp.hparams(hparams)  # record the values used in this trial
        accuracy, model, fitted_model = create_fit_keras_model(hparams, version_data_control, optimizer_name, validation_method, callbacks)
        tf.summary.scalar(METRIC_ACCURACY, accuracy, step=1)
    
    return model, fitted_model
```

```py
"""
Model Training
"""
hp_logging_directory=os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "model_one\\logs\\hparam_tuning") #initialize the logging directory

HP_HIDDEN_UNITS = hp.HParam('batch_size', hp.Discrete([32, 64, 128]))
HP_EMBEDDING_DIM = hp.HParam('embedding_dim', hp.Discrete([100, 200, 300]))
HP_LEARNING_RATE = hp.HParam('learning_rate', hp.Discrete([0.001, 0.01, 0.1])) # Adam default: 0.001, SGD default: 0.01, RMSprop default: 0.001
HP_DECAY_STEPS_MULTIPLIER = hp.HParam('decay_steps_multiplier', hp.Discrete([100, 1000]))

METRIC_ACCURACY = "f1_score" #auc

with tf.summary.create_file_writer(hp_logging_directory).as_default():
    hp.hparams_config(
    hparams=[HP_HIDDEN_UNITS, HP_EMBEDDING_DIM, HP_LEARNING_RATE, HP_DECAY_STEPS_MULTIPLIER],
    metrics=[hp.Metric(METRIC_ACCURACY, display_name='f1_score')], #AUC
  )

try:
    os.path.exists(hp_logging_directory)
    print("Directory of hyper parameters logging exists!")
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    print("Directory not found!")

begin_time=time.time()
print("{0}: Start execution of the cell\n".format(datetime.utcnow().strftime(date_format)))

session_num = 1

for batch_size in HP_HIDDEN_UNITS.domain.values:
    for embedding_dim in HP_EMBEDDING_DIM.domain.values:
        for learning_rate in HP_LEARNING_RATE.domain.values:
            for decay_steps_multiplier in HP_DECAY_STEPS_MULTIPLIER.domain.values:
                hparams = {
                    HP_HIDDEN_UNITS: batch_size,
                    HP_EMBEDDING_DIM: embedding_dim,
                    HP_LEARNING_RATE: learning_rate,
                    HP_DECAY_STEPS_MULTIPLIER: decay_steps_multiplier
                  }
                run_name = "run-id {0}".format(session_num)
                total_number_models=(len(HP_HIDDEN_UNITS.domain.values)*len(HP_EMBEDDING_DIM.domain.values)*len(HP_LEARNING_RATE.domain.values)*len(HP_DECAY_STEPS_MULTIPLIER.domain.values))
                print('--- Starting trial: {0}/{1}\n'.format(run_name, total_number_models))
                print({h.name: hparams[h] for h in hparams}, '\n')

                starting_training=time.time()

                model_struture, model_history=run('{0}\\'.format(hp_logging_directory) + run_name, 
                                                  hparams, 
                                                  version_data_control, 
                                                  "adam", 
                                                  "validation_split",
                                                  callback(folder_path_model_saved, 
                                                           "{0}_{1}dim_{2}batchsize_{3}lr_{4}decaymultiplier_{5}".format(saved_model_name,
                                                                                                                         str(embedding_dim), 
                                                                                                                         str(batch_size), 
                                                                                                                         str(learning_rate), 
                                                                                                                         str(decay_steps_multiplier),
                                                                                                                         version_data_control),
                                                           fit_parameters["patience_value"],
                                                           "{0}\\".format(hp_logging_directory) + datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S"), 
                                                           hparams))
                
                print("Average time per epoch: {0}\n".format(format_timespan((time.time()-starting_training)/len(model_history.epoch))))
```

As you can see I use the class_weigths argument to introduce the weights of positive and negative class. However, when I executing the script I have the following output:

[image]
[image]
[image]

**Please write in the comments if any additional information would be helpful.**
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does anyone have any input on this yet? Please write in the comments if I forgot to include something or you may need any additional clarification

Comment: Is is possible for you to share reproducible example on collab ?

Comment: Yeah it is! I have lots of data but I will shrink them and I will post the notebook from Colab. :)

Comment: @mujjiga I will post here the notebook in a couple of hours. Thank you for the response :)

Comment: @mujjiga I have added the relevant colab notebook.

Comment: @mujjiga any update on this? Did you managed to replicate the issue? Shall I open a GitHub issue?